# Can themes be exported and imported?

Tags: export, customization, import, theme

If I create a theme, can I export it for import later or for distribution?

Comment: Since there are import/export buttons very visable in the interface, IMHO this could be closed/marked as invalid.

Comment: @ideasman42 but they won't appear in a vanilla installation, you manually have to enable the export theme addon, which isn't (to my knowledge) included in addons or addons_contrib by default at present.

Comment: @ideasman42 as zeffii said, not by default. I didn't even remember there was such an addon included (remember there are possibly over a hundred addons included with Blender). This is still quite a valid question as it is not something easily discoverable.

Answer (score 9):

The themes are saved as an XML file under `scripts/presets/interface_theme`. You can manually navigate to there and grab the XML files.

Installing a theme is easier, you can use the `install Theme...` button in user preference panel.

Answer (score 9):

Open User Preferences, go to Themes, change stuff and then click on the plus symbol next to the theme selection button:

[image: there's the button]

Next, type in a name for the file (without extension):

[image: naming dialog]

Click OK and you should be able to find the file (XML file, in this case "the_best_theme.xml") in one of the following folders (depending on operating system):

#### Windows

`%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\[YOUR VERSION]\scripts\presets\interface_theme\`

#### Mac OSX

`/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/[YOUR VERSION]/scripts/presets/interface_theme/`

#### Linux

`$HOME/.config/blender/[YOUR VERSION]/scripts/presets/interface_theme/`

If it is not in one of them, it might be in the subdirectory `.../scripts/presets/interface_theme/` of some other configuration directory as descibed here: https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html

Answer (score 4):

in OSX you will find the xml files you've saved in

/Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.65/scripts/presets/interface_theme

I don't know what OS you're on but this helped me on OSX.